# aggregate function on separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions, max

I'm trying to select most recent date from one table (invoice) to a customer on another table. I'm not looking for a single customer, but several. What I want to do looks something like this:

```
select C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State], I.[Date]  
From myDb.dbo.Customer C  
left join myDb.dbo.Invoice I on I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID  
where c.state=@State and i.date = max(i.date)
```

I know I can't have the `Max()` in the where, and I tried using `HAVING`. I can't assign a local var for the `customerID` and do a `where i.date = (select...)`.  I'm trying to keep this all as one statement as this is being executed on several DB's from a single DB.

update:
I've decided to change my design requirements as this wasn't the most optimal solution.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question or not.  You want to get a list of all customers from a specific state and the date of their respective last invoices?

Comment: Why would there be multiple customers on a single invoice?

Comment: it would be a listing of all customers and what state, with the most recent invoice date for each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly want to group:

```
select C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State], max(I.[Date]) as [Date]
from myDb.dbo.Customer C
    left join myDb.dbo.Invoice I on I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
where C.state = @State
group by C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State]
```

Updated:

```
select A.[Last Name], A.[First Name], A.[State], B.[Date]
from myDb.dbo.Customer A
    join (
        -- Get Customers by State with their most recent Invoice Date
        select C.[CustomerID], max(I.[Date]) as [Date]
        from myDb.dbo.Customer C
            left join myDb.dbo.Invoice I on I.[CustomerID] = C.[CustomerID]
        where C.[State] = @State
        group by C.[CustomerID]
    ) B on A.[CustomerID] = B.[CustomerID]
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work if the customer has moved to a different state, I get a duplicate result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the where clause, then, but I've put up another possibility.

Comment: you proved the most helpful, so, I'll mark this as the answer just to close out the question. Thanks for the help. Decided to just change the design some.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
select C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State], I.[Date]  
From myDb.dbo.Customer C  
left join myDb.dbo.Invoice I on I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID  
where c.state=@State 
) select * from cte where cte.Date = (select max (cte.Date) from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

Derived table returns last invoice date per customer. This is then joined back with customer.

```
select C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State], LastInvoice.LastInvoiceDate
from myDb.dbo.Customer C  
inner join
(
    select I.CustomerID, max (I.Date) LastInvoiceDate
      from myDb.dbo.Invoice I
     group by I.CustomerID
) LastInvoice
  on C.CustomerID = LastInvoice.CustomerID
```

There can be duplication if customer had more invoices on the same day (presumably dates do not contain time component). You might sort it out with distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.[Last Name], C.[First Name], C.[State], I.[Date] ,
(select top 1 date from invoice I where I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID order by date desc)
From myDb.dbo.Customer C
```